# Ionic Record Audio on Android - how to change rate?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, media

I'm using the Media Ionic plugin successfully to record, save and play audio file on Android.

I can't seem to understand how to use the setRate() function that comes with it.

Is there other ways to increase quality of sound?

```
this.MediaFile = this.media.create(filename) // ionic native
this.MediaFile.startRecord();
```

Versions are:

```
ionic: 3.19.0
@ionic-native/media: 4.5.2
cordova-plugin-media: 3.0.1
```

Comment: version of ionic? are you using ionic native? version of media ionic plugin?

Comment: versions added above

Comment: just use:  `this.MediaFile.setRate(2.0)` for example

Comment: What does the number represent?

Comment: It's a speed rate @GuyC

Comment: wow, I was sure it was either bit rate or sample rate. Is there a way to change either of these then?

Comment: With this plugin, I dont see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161574/discussion-between-guyc-and-fetrarij).